# how would i create this in html where the text is aligned with each other

Tags: html, css

Im trying to create this for my current code,how do i do this ?This is for a price calculator and i need an example before i start coding it
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xE4f.png

```
      <div class="grid-item">
        <thead>
          <td>App-Benutzer</td><br>
          <td>pro 7,50€</td><br>
          <td>Backend-Benutzer</td><br>
          <td>pro 35,50€</td><br>
        </thead>
        <hr>
        <span class='summe'>0.00</span><br>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please dont ask for 'free code' on Stack overflow. You need to try it yourself first and then ask for help if you get stuck.

Comment: Your code is not 'legal' HTML. Please read up about how to create an HTML table and be careful to understand what elements can be children and parents of what other elements. In this case a thead cannot be a direct child of a div and a td cannot be a direct child of a thead. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table and related documentation, correct your code and if you are still stuck make your code into a runnable snippet and describe what isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code. You can create your details as a table

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>`
table, th, td {
  border:1px solid black;
}
</style>
<body>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>App-Benutzer
    </td>
    <td>75,00€</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Backend-Benutzer</td>
    <td>175,00€</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```